# How do i deal with this memory leak in this C 90 code?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

The code roughly works like this:
given in input a matrix and the value of it's columns and rows the algorithm searches the shortest path with a preference for certains cells to move on.

Here is the part of the code I am talking about:

```
/* Function to find the shortest path in the matrix using BFS */
void findShortestPath(Matrix *matrix, Result *bestResult) {
    int numRows = matrix->rows;
    int numCols = matrix->cols;
    int **visited = (int **)malloc(numRows * sizeof(int * ));
    int i, newDistance, newBadCells, newNegativeCells, row, col, distance, badCells, negativeCells;
    int dx[] = {
        -1,
        1,
        0,
        0
    };
    int dy[] = {
        0,
        0,
        -1,
        1
    };
    BFSNode currentNode;
    BFSNode *queue = (BFSNode *)malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(BFSNode));
    int queueSize = 0;
    char *path;
    char *check = "";

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        visited[i] = (int *)malloc(numCols * sizeof(int));
        memset(visited[i], 0, numCols * sizeof(int));
    }

    enqueue(queue, &queueSize, createBFSNode(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ""));

    while (queueSize > 0) {
        qsort(queue, queueSize, sizeof(BFSNode), priorityCompare);

        currentNode = dequeue(queue, &queueSize);
        row = currentNode.point.row;
        col = currentNode.point.col;
        distance = currentNode.distance;
        badCells = currentNode.badCells;
        negativeCells = currentNode.negativeCells;
        path = currentNode.path;

        if (row == numRows - 1 && col == numCols - 1) {
            if (bestResult->distance == -1 || distance < bestResult->distance) {
                bestResult->distance = distance;
                bestResult->badCells = badCells;
                bestResult->negativeCells = negativeCells;
                free(bestResult->path);
                bestResult->path = strdup(path);
            } else if (distance == bestResult->distance && negativeCells > bestResult->negativeCells) {
                bestResult->badCells = badCells;
                bestResult->negativeCells = negativeCells;
                free(bestResult->path);
                bestResult->path = strdup(path);
            }

            continue;
        }

        visited[row][col] = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int newRow = row + dy[i];
            int newCol = col + dx[i];

            if (isValidMove(matrix, newRow, newCol, visited)) {
                char *newPath = (char *)malloc((strlen(path) + 2) * sizeof(char));
                if (newPath == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                strcpy(newPath, path);

                if (i == 0) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'O';
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'E';
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'N';
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'S';
                }
                newPath[strlen(path) + 1] = '\0';

                newDistance = distance + 1;
                newBadCells = badCells + (matrix->matrix[newRow][newCol] == 0);
                newNegativeCells = negativeCells + (matrix->matrix[newRow][newCol] == -1);

                enqueue(queue, & queueSize, createBFSNode(newRow, newCol, newDistance, newBadCells, newNegativeCells, newPath));
                visited[newRow][newCol] = 1;
            }
        }

        if (path == check) {} else {
            free(path);
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        free(visited[i]);
    }
    free(visited);
    free(queue);
}
```

This variable that **causes a memory leak** is **newPath** but it's not that simple, let me explain

The memory allocation works like this:
The queue starts with an empty/starter node with no memory allocated for the path
Then for every node following that a path is allocated as "**newPath**" each time before enqueueing the node and it's later on freed as "**path**" when dequeueing the node.

Through debugging I have found out that the amount of `**free**()` is one short than the `**malloc**()` amount so it ends up not being able to free one block of memory

All the other memory is allocated and freed correctly

I've tried many different implementations to solve the problem but they all failed doing so

Some of them were:

```
 while (queueSize > 0) {
     qsort(queue, queueSize, sizeof(BFSNode), priorityCompare);

     currentNode = dequeue(queue, & queueSize);
     row = currentNode.point.row;
     col = currentNode.point.col;
     distance = currentNode.distance;
     badCells = currentNode.badCells;
     negativeCells = currentNode.negativeCells;
     /* With a switch check if it's the first node or not then free path before the new value is assigned */
     path = currentNode.path;
```

or

freeing path an additional time after the while is ended

**EDIT**
Hopefully the indentation is fixed now

**newPath is freed through path as they share the same memory allocation**

Could any of you help me figure out a way to fix this issue?
**Thank you all for your time and help!**

Comment: Please edit your code and fix the indentation so it's consistent.  Right now, it's hard to read.

Comment: You may want to use some conservative garbage collector like (Boehm's GC)[https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc], or you could (this is harder) implement your own one.

Comment: All those `strlen(path)` are doing my head in - plus I don't see a single free of newPath

Comment: I added some edits i hope it's a bit more clear like this

Comment: Better, but right now everything is indented by 4-5 blanks; could you remove those? (And, if I counted correctly, your first and last `else`s are indented inconsistently. This is minor, but you might as well fix this too.)

Comment: I formatted the code via [CodeBeautify](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier#) (no affiliation) plus some manual cleanups.  If you have trouble keeping your code well formatted as you write, then you should really look into a formatter.  There are many available, both online and offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you accept a result as the (to-date) best, you do this (in both control paths):

> ```
>                 free(bestResult->path);
>                 bestResult->path = strdup(path);
> ```

and then `continue` to the next iteration of the loop.  Thus, you skip the code that frees the `path` of the current node, and that node object is then lost.  That's your leak.  You could in fact leak more than one allocated object, depending on the input.

I suppose you are performing that `strdup()` instead of a simple assignment because the current node's path may sometimes be a pointer to a string literal, which downstream code consuming the shortest path result must not try to free. But this has forced you to make several distortions to your code.  Instead, why not prevent any node containing such a path pointer in the first place?

Additional recommendations:

- don't rely on the caller-provided initial contents of `*bestResult` unless that's *really* what you mean to do.  I'm inclined to think it's not, but that's hard to say.
- avoid simulating multi-dimensional arrays via arrays of pointers.  You cannot use variable-length arrays in C90, but you can still simulate 2D arrays on top of 1D arrays, and this can be both cleaner and faster.
- declare your variables in the narrowest possible scope.
- do not declare multiple variables in the same statement.
- prefer to assign initial values to your variables in their declarations
  when that is feasible
- do not cast the result of `malloc` *etc*.
- prefer `calloc()` over `malloc()` + `memset`-to-zero.
- generally speaking, compute allocation sizes based on the variable to which you are assigning the resulting pointer.  This is more resilient and less error-prone than hard-coding a data type in the size calculation.
- Generally speaking, don't say `sizeof(char)`, as this is 1 *by definition*.
- prefer to minimize code duplication.  This is a fair justification for a small number of unneeded computations.
- consider not writing to the out parameter until you have a final value for it.  This preserves the caller's original value in the event that the function fails.
- consider declaring pointer parameters as pointers to `const` objects when the function indeed can promise to not modify the pointed-to object.
- find a better way to do that path concatenation.

For example,

```
/* Function to find the shortest path in the matrix using BFS */
void findShortestPath(const Matrix *matrix, Result *bestResult) {
    static const int dx[] = { -1, 1, 0, 0 };
    static const int dy[] = { 0, 0, -1, 1 };
    static const char dir[][2] = { "O", "E", "N", "S" };

    int numRows = matrix->rows;
    int numCols = matrix->cols;

    // Note: this restructuring will require changes to isValidMove(), too:
    int *visited = calloc(numRows * numCols, sizeof(*visited));
    #define VISITED(r, c) (visited[(r) * numCols + (c)])

    BFSNode *queue = malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(*queue));
    int queueSize = 0;

    enqueue(queue, &queueSize, createBFSNode(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, strdup("")));

    // Reproduce the original code's dependence on the initial value
    // of *bestResult:
    Result workingBest = *bestResult;

    // Alternatively:
    // Result workingBest = { -1, 0, 0, NULL };  // check element order

    while (queueSize > 0) {
        qsort(queue, queueSize, sizeof(*queue), priorityCompare);

        BFSNode currentNode = dequeue(queue, &queueSize);
        int row = currentNode.point.row;
        int col = currentNode.point.col;
        // Check member order:
        Result result = {
           currentNode.distance,
           currentNode.badCells,
           currentNode.negativeCells,
           currentNode.path
        };

        if (row == numRows - 1 && col == numCols - 1) {
            if ((workingBest.distance == -1)
                    || (result.distance < workingBest.distance) 
                    || (result.distance == workingBest.distance
                            && result.negativeCells > workingBest.negativeCells)) {
                free(workingBest.path);
                workingBest = result;
            }

            continue;
        }

        VISITED(row, col) = 1;

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int newRow = row + dy[i];
            int newCol = col + dx[i];

            if (isValidMove(matrix, newRow, newCol, visited)) {
                char *newPath = malloc(strlen(result.path) + 2);

                if (newPath == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                sprintf(newPath, "%s%s", result.path, dir[i]);

                int newDistance = result.distance + 1;
                int newBadCells = result.badCells + (matrix->matrix[newRow][newCol] == 0);
                int newNegativeCells = result.negativeCells + (matrix->matrix[newRow][newCol] == -1);

                enqueue(queue, &queueSize, createBFSNode(
                            newRow, newCol, newDistance, newBadCells, newNegativeCells, newPath));
                VISITED(newRow, newCol) = 1;
            }
        }

        free(result.path);
    }

    free(visited);
    free(queue);

    *bestResult = workingBest;
    #undef VISITED
}
```

Comment: It was, indeed, that section of code! Thanks for all the great tips aswell, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation method is confusing:

```
                strcpy(newPath, path);

                if (i == 0) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'O';
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'E';
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'N';
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    newPath[strlen(path)] = 'S';
                }
                newPath[strlen(path) + 1] = '\0';
```

You should instead write:

```
                strcpy(newPath, path);
                if (i == 0) {
                    strcat(newPath, "O");
                } else if (i == 1) {
                    strcat(newPath, "E");
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    strcat(newPath, "N");
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    strcat(newPath, "S");
                }
```

Also note that `malloc(numRows * numCols * sizeof(BFSNode))` is error prone as `numRows` and `numCols` have type `int`, so `numRows * numCols` may overflow.  You should write:

```
    BFSNode *queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue) * numRows * numCols);
```

Comment: I'm not following your criticism.  Yes, `newPath`'s terminator is overwritten, but that does not affect the validity of `strlen(path)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: you are correct, confusing code bit me :)